# D3.js padded brush selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have created a scatterplot with D3.js that will scale the axises and the size of the points based upon the loaded data, meaning the scale of the data and the size of the points can vary wildly from chart-to-chart.  I am trying to use brush selection to select points on the chart whose area falls under the brush selection extent (not just the absolute x-y position of the data point).  So in essence, given two points at the same position, the point with the larger radius would be easier to select.  I am not quite sure how to take the pixel-padding of the point into consideration when performing the brush select.  How do I scale the known pixel value of the point padding to a chart value that can be used when evaluating my selection?

Here is my brush definition:

```
var brush = svg.append("g")
        .datum(function() { return {selected: false}; })
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(d3.svg.brush()
            .x(x)
            .y(y)
            .on("brushstart", function(d) {
                selectedNodes = {};
            })
            .on("brush", function() {
                var extent = d3.event.target.extent();
                dot.classed("selected", function(d) {
                    if (extent[0][0] <= d.x 
                        && d.x <= extent[1][0] 
                        && extent[0][1] <= d.y
                        && d.y <= extent[1][1])
                    {
                        return d.selected = true; 
                    } else {
                        return d.selected = false; 
                    }
                });
            })
            .on("brushend", function() {
                d3.select(this).call(d3.event.target);
            }));
```

And the point definition:

```
var dot = svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("r", function(d,i) { return d.r; }) 
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
            return x(d.x);
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return y(d.y);
        });
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Do you want to modify the brush behaviour to "snap" to data points?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I would like my brush selection to snare points on the graph by their svg element area, not their absolute X,Y coordinates.  So a circle with a large radius would be easier to select than one with a small radius.  Is this clear?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. You would need to detect whether the current brush extent touches/intersects a shape in the brush handler, and if it does set the extent to the centre of the shape.